# VisualState AdaptiveTrigger not firing

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

i watched the session "From the Small Screen to the Big Screen: Building Universal Windows App Experiences with XAML" from the BUILD event. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-679

I´d like to try the AdaptiveTrigger but it doesn´t fire with my minimal Windows 10 UWP app.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowSizeStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="rect.Fill" Value="Beige" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="rect.Fill" Value="White" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RelativePanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="100" Height="100" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Fill="Beige"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

But nothing happens. It seems that the trigger is simply not fired. Did i miss something?

Regards!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it happens when you put the groups in the Page instead inside the first control. Try put inside:

```
<Grid...>
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

</Grid>
```

Apart if you want to make more complex adaptative triggers I made an article here: [codeproject advanced view states](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/896974/Advanced-View-States-for-Windows-apps)

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
I tried to place the VisualStateManager into the RelativePanel before which didn´t work either.

Comment: I've noticed that during the last or three releases of VS2017 that my AdaptiveTriggers aren't working correctly, but only during debug.  If I start the app with VS they do not work, if I start normally by clicking the app from a tile they do. :(  I am on VS2017 15.5.4.  Anyone else?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I had this problem, too. For me, I finally figured out that the issue was with targeting elements where loading is deferred (x:Load) in the Visual States. There seems to be a bug where if you are debugging in Visual Studio, and your VisualState changes an element that is not loaded yet (due to x:Load) via an AdaptiveTrigger, the AdaptiveTriggers do not work. But they work fine when running the same app build outside of debugging. Hope that's helpful.